# SQL Update when not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to set a column in the fabcon table only if the original column is null.

This is the code I've already tried.

```
UPDATE  dbo.fabcon
SET     ext = COALESCE(ext, ( SELECT CASE WHEN [<3] IS NOT NULL THEN '3' END AS     extent
                                       FROM dbo.spreadsheetData ))
```

This is the error I'm getting:
    Sub-query returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the sub-query follows `=, !=, <, <= , >, >=` or when the sub-query is used as an expression.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Thanks. :)

EDIT: the two tables fabcon and spreadsheetData are linked by a column called main1

EDIT2: I've updated the query to this:

```
UPDATE dbo.fabcon
 SET  ext = (SELECT CASE WHEN [<3] IS NOT NULL THEN '3' END 
          FROM dbo.spreadsheetData ssd
          WHERE ssd.id = fabcon.id
         )
 WHERE ext IS NULL;
```

However, its still failing with the same error.

Comment: How are your two tables related?

Comment: Original column implies there is a link between the 2 tables, which you can use. What is the link?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  The error message is pretty obvious.  Your subquery is returning more than one row.  It doesn't even have a `where` clause, so this is not surprising.

Comment: I have updated the original question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: So the tables spreadsheetData and fabcon are 1:1 related and have the same id? This is a possible model, but then you wouldn't get the error. So obviously the tables are not 1:1 related, they don't have the same id and the statement should probably be something like this instead: `WHERE ssd.id = fabcon.id_ssd`.

Comment: If it's still failing with the same error then you still have more than one row in `spreadSheetData` for some particular `ID` value(s).

Comment: Yup, completely 1:1. With those same unique IDs against each record.

Comment: Sorry, just ran a query to check if there are some duplicate records and there are. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a link between the table `fabcon` and `spreadsheetData`.  Assuming it is called `id`:

```
UPDATE dbo.fabcon
  SET  ext = (SELECT CASE WHEN [<3] IS NOT NULL THEN '3' END) 
              FROM dbo.spreadsheetData ssd
              WHERE ssd.id = fabcon.id
             )
  WHERE ext IS NULL;
```

Note that I removed the `coalesce()` and replaced it with a `where` clause for the update.  This prevents the query from updating rows unnecessarily (with unchanged values).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @PAth INT 
 Select @path =  COALESCE(ext,'')+[<3]+';' FROM  dbo.spreadsheetData 

UPDATE dbo.fabcon
            SET     ext = CASE WHEN @PAth IS NOT NULL 
        THEN '3' ELSE '' 
         END AS Extent
             FROM dbo.fabcon f WHERE f.id = @path
```

may be this works i think

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Assuming I have understood your original query correctly

```
UPDATE dbo.fabcon 
  SET 
    ext = ssd.[column to insert data from]
FROM 
    dbo.spreadsheetData ssd
WHERE 
    ext IS NULL
    AND 
        fabcon.id = ssd.id
```

This assumes the id in the ssd table is the id from the fabcon table. Otherwise just change the id matching based on your column specification

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbo.fabcon
 SET  ext = (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN [<3] IS NOT NULL THEN '3' END 
          FROM dbo.spreadsheetData ssd
          WHERE ssd.main1 = fabcon.main1
          ORDER BY 1
         )
 WHERE ext IS NULL;
```

with the 2 tables related via "main1" (as now indicated) and an arbitrary "TOP 1" thrown in to avoid the error, this might work.

but: the best way to get an answer is to provide some sample data and an expected result